# Shift + Ctrl + Z not working in any application in Windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

First of to mention that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> works fine so it is not a layout issue, also I tried English us as well as English uk and issue mentioned still remains, also it is present in multiple programs, so it is not particular program to blame.

As everyone probably knows this is Redo shortcuts in a lot of programs but It doesn't work unless I use right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on keyboard which is not optimal since I  have to use two hands in that case.

For some reason <kbd>Z</kbd> can't be pressed at the same time with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but if I use right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> it works fine, this is the only combination I found that doesn't work otherwise everything works fine, this issue is present on 2 devices that I could test One laptop with integrated keyboard running Windows 10 and Desktop with regular qwerty keyboard running Windows 11

Comment: First, some apps use CTRL+Y as the Redo shortcut, and not CTRL+SHIFT+Z, like Thunderbird. I don't see any reply to your question, in fact, I don't see any question... A generic solution to all those keys problems is AutoHotKey.

Comment: Maybe some other app is hooking the left CTRL? Did you try closing/killing the maximum you could? And which apps work, don't, system, keyboard... I'm afraid with few proper details you won't get a solution.

Comment: I tried booting to safe mode and issue is still present. I tried closing any app in background manually (non essential but i guess that safe mode does that better than me) and still have the issue.

Comment: If you took time and actually read the question you would find most of details there. If I ask question where I say it doesn't work it means it doesn't work. In what apps? Well it doesn't work so it means all apps where is set as default and in those where I tried to set it I couldn't because that key combination can't be pressed. crtl + shift works in  combination with any other key but Z.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with hardware itself.

My keyboard behaves the same with another PC on which another keyboard works fine, I didn't tried that normal working keyboard on my PC but it is obvious that it is hardware related issue, stay away from no name cheap keyboards.

Only solution would be to either buy another keyboard or change shortcut to combination that isn't used and is easy to press with one hand.